# $X$ is $\text{Exp}(\lambda)$, $Y$ is $\text{Uniform}(0,X)$. How can I find $\Bbb E[Y]$ and $\text{Var}(Y)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-function

$X$ is $\text{Exp}(\lambda)$, $Y$ is $\text{Uniform}(0,X)$. How can I find $\Bbb E[Y]$ and $\text{Var}(Y)$?

I did tried to plug it like double integral of $\Bbb E[Y]$ from 0 to X which $f(t)$ is $\text{Exp}(\lambda)$.
But I could not solve it. Could anyone point or hint me?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean E[Y] and Var[Y]

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets use conditional expectation. Compute $$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|X]]$$

Now $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$ is the mean of a uniform [0,X] which is $X/2$.
Thus $$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \mathbb{E}[X/2]= \frac{1}{2\lambda}$$

Similarly you can get the variance by working with 
$$\mathbb{E}[Y^2] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y^2|X]]$$

Comment: I do not know about this $E[Y] = E[E[Y|X]]$ before.
Thank you for your answer. I will try to solve the variance by myself.

Comment: It's called the law of iterated expectation. Was this not covered? Any other way would be laborious.

Answer (score 2):

First we see that for $x\geq 0$ we have
$$
E[Y\mid X=x]=\frac{x}{2}
$$
and so
$$
E[Y\mid X]=\frac{X}{2}.
$$
Now use that 
$$
E[Y]=E[E[Y\mid X]].
$$
For the variance you can use a similar argument using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance).

Answer (score 2):

For finding the variance of $Y$, you can use the total variance formula which gives
$$\begin{align*}
\text{var}(Y) &= E[\text{var}(Y\mid X)] + \text{var}(E[Y\mid X])\\
&= E\left[\frac{X^2}{12}\right] + \text{var}\left(\frac{X}{2}\right)
\end{align*}$$

**Edit** Note to OP: I just noticed that Stefan Hansen's answer already pointed out 
the total variance formula to you, but the second line above adds a
little detail to get you further along the way.

Comment: I did it by finding $E[E[X^2]]$ based on Gautam Shenoy hints. Then find $$Var(Y) = E[Y^2] - E[Y]^2 $$
By the way, thank you for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation

Use the conditional distribution of $Y$ if $X$ is known.

Comment: That is a good hint but unfortunately I already saw other post.
Thank you.